# Cordova: How to use two sqlite plugins at once?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, spatialite

I'm building an cordova app which uses some plugins that need to use different cordova-sqlite-plugins. One plugin needs [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext) installed, another plugin needs [cordova-spatialite-storage](https://github.com/DisyInformationssysteme/Cordova-spatialite-storage).

My problem now is, that I can't get both plugins to run simultaneously. Only the last installed plugin is used. They are both based on [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage), so maybe it's a problem that both uses the same syntax (window.sqlitePlugin)? Is it possible to use both plugins with different variables, so I can call the plugin I want to use in my JavaScript code?

Any help / hints / tips are welcome!

Comment: I found a hint..."It is not possible to install multiple sqlite plugins. Duplicate symbols will result. This will be documented as a pitfall."
(https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext/issues/67)

It concerns different plugins, but I think it is the same issue in this case. Maybe there is a way to get around this (since this post is from 2017)?